# Access DbContext from within partial class in EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, hangfire

I'm building a Hangfire application and I've scaffolded the database to EF Core. Now I've created a new partial class and from within that new partial I would like to access the `DbContext` so I can do some ledger stuff.

But DI does not seem to work, does anyone have another solution?

File 1

```
public partial class Config
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public bool IsUserManaged { get; set; }

    public string ConfigurationGroup { get; set; }

    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModificationTime { get; set; }

    public int? LastModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

File 2

```
public partial class Config
{
    private IDbContextFactory<DataContext> _dataContext;
 
    public Config(IDbContextFactory<DataContext> dataContext)
    {
        _dataContext = dataContext
    }

    public static T GetConfigValue<T>(string key, T defaultValue, DataContext existingContext = null)
    {
        if (existingContext != null)
        {
            return GetConfigValue(existingContext, key, defaultValue);
        }
 
        return GetConfigValue(_dataContext, key, defaultValue);
    }

    public static T GetConfigValue<T>(DataContext ctx, string key)
    {
        return GetConfigValue(ctx, key, default(T));
    }

    public static T GetConfigValue<T>(DataContext ctx, string key, T defaultValue)
    {
        var value = GetRawConfigValue(ctx, key);
 
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) 
            return defaultValue;

        try
        {
            var conv = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
            var item = (T)conv.ConvertFrom(null, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, value);

            return item;
        }
        catch
        {
            return defaultValue;
        }
    }

    private static readonly Func<DataContext, string, string> GetRawConfigValue =
        (context, key) => (from c in context.Configs
                           where c.Name == key.ToString()
                           select c.Value).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Init for the DbContext in program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<DataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

The DI does work on all other places, but only not in the partial class for the EF Core model

Comment: Please also show how you configure the DI container.

Comment: _"But DI does not seem to work, does anyone have another solution?"_ - how exactly it does not work? Do you have a full [mre]?

Comment: I've updated the original question.

Comment: That code shouldn't even compile. You have an injected instance on the constructor but are trying to access it from within a `static` method. That won't work. You can use a static initializer or better, a proper Singleton which is initialized once your DI container is set up, that the domain classes etc. access, though an Entity should really have no need to ever reference a DbContext.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection not work for static, you could make a instance by `using`

```
        public static T GetConfigValue<T>(string key, T defaultValue, DataContext existingContext = null)
        {
            ...

            using (var datacontext = new DataContext())
            {
                return GetConfigValue(dataContext, key, defaultValue);

            }
            
        }
```